# Tree-based Documentation for PHP web application

Tags: php, web-applications

I have a PHP web application and I want to implement documentation for the application so that users can navigate through a treeview. Something similar to MSDN of Microsoft.

I also want options for exporting the documentation as PDF

Is there any package that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Most Wikis will provide some sort of export functionality, although not all provide tree structured navigation. I use dokuwiki a lot which has [several plugins](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin%3abookcreator) for PDF creation.